# CreateNamedPipe ERROR_INVALID_NAME

Tags: multithreading, winapi, visual-c++, named-pipes

Code snippet:

```
void RunThread(void* unused_args)
{
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sdsc;
    ULONG size;
    ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor("S:(ML;;NW;;;LW)", SDDL_REVISION_1, &sdsc, &size);
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);
    sa.bInheritHandle = false;
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = sdsc;
    HANDLE pipe = CreateNamedPipe("\\.\pipe\mmaivpc_test_pipe", PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX, PIPE_TYPE_BYTE, 255, 1024, 1024, 0, &sa);
    DWORD error = GetLastError();
}
```

If you haven't figured it out from the function name, this function is getting called by `_beginthread`.  `GetLastError()` is returning `ERROR_INVALID_NAME` and I can not figure out why.

Comment: You were ignoring the warnings, right? Usual practice by most programmers, don't know why!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the backslashes in the string literal being used for the pipe name:

```
HANDLE pipe = CreateNamedPipe("\\\\.\\pipe\\mmaivpc_test_pipe",
                              PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX, 
                              PIPE_TYPE_BYTE, 255, 1024, 1024, 0, &sa);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should escape your back slashes :)

Answer (score 1):

If you used forward slashes / in your paths your code would be more readable, and you would avoid errors like this.

Not many people seem to know that windows accepts both /and \ as the directory separator.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the same way  for network shares also , like \\server1 , we have to represent in c++ as \\\\server1
to escape '\' we have to use  one more '\'

Comment: hi, did you tried this, or any solution you got, curious to know what is working

Answer (score 0):

Wrap an argument lpName into TEXT(), like this:

```
HANDLE pipe = CreateNamedPipe(TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\mmaivpc_test_pipe"), PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX, PIPE_TYPE_BYTE, 255, 1024, 1024, 0, &sa);
```

and the name must be in format `\\\\.\\pipe\\your_pipe_name`.
Name of a pipe is not case sensitive.

Here is good example https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365588(v=vs.85).aspx