# Is there a way to SendMessage from a console to another?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a project, and in this project there are 2 console application programs. Is there any chance that a way exists to send a message (using SendMessage() or clipboard method) from one console to another?

I mean, if I have a value in console 1, how can I pass it to console 2 when I change the value?

Comment: The answer is yes. There a myriad of ways to do inter-process communication on Windows either with windows messages or other appropriate IPC mechanism. **What are you really trying to do?**  Knowing what you are trying to accomplish will suggest the best answers.

Comment: i need to pass just a string from a console window to another, that's all!

Comment: @SerbanMarin-Eusebiu there are MANY MANY MANY ways to exchange data between provesses. You are going to have to narrow the focus of your question.

Comment: i don't think so, because, i am restricted to use just winapi for this thing, and i couldn't find anything to help me.

Comment: What do you mean by "pass a string".  You want to paste into the other console window.  Or programmatically receive it through some callback?   You gotta be more specific to get help here, Serban.

Comment: Can [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output?redirectedfrom=MSDN) solve your problem?

Comment: @ZhuSong-MSFT that was a little bit what i need!!!!

Comment: @selbie, i mean, in console one, to write something in a variable, and in the second program, to receive the variable that i've written in the first console.

Comment: @SerbanMarin-Eusebiu Could you specify what else is needed?

Comment: @SerbanMarin-Eusebiu - this is the last time I'll ask.  **What are you really trying to do**?  This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You think you need to send a string between console applications, but if you elaborate on the scenario instead of the technical, the best technical answer can be presented?.

Comment: Is that two separate programs? do you know the name of each program?

Comment: yes, that's it, i've make a missundestanding, i have 2 programs in one big program, when i write the value in first console, i want that value to be received by the second program, and to do what it need to do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve your needs, such as shared memory, pipes, message queues, etc.

I use pipes here to introduce you to the specific steps of inter-process communication.

Here is the sender code:

```
#define BUF_SIZE 4096
HANDLE h_Mypipe = NULL;
//Step 1: Define the pipe name, dot means current host, pipe means pipe
#define MY_NAMED_PIPE   L"\\\\.\\pipe\\Named_Pipe"
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //Step 2: Create a named pipe
    h_Mypipe = CreateNamedPipe(
        MY_NAMED_PIPE, //Create a name for the named pipe
        PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX, //Pipeline access mode: PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX refers to two-way mode
        PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | //Write method of named pipe handle: write to the pipe as a data block
        PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE | //Read method of named pipe handle: read from the pipe in the form of a data block
        PIPE_WAIT, //Waiting mode of named pipe handle: blocking mode
        PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES, //The maximum number of instances that the pipeline can create: 1~255,
        0, //The output buffer capacity of the pipeline, 0 means the default size
        0, //The input buffer capacity of the pipeline, 0 means the default size
        1000, //The default waiting timeout of the pipeline, in milliseconds
        NULL); //The security of the pipeline, NULL means the default security provided by windows
    if (h_Mypipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        cout << "Create Named_Pipe Failed..." << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    //Step 3: Wait for the client to connect
    if (!ConnectNamedPipe(h_Mypipe, NULL))
    {
        cout << "Connect Failed..." << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else
        cout << "Connect Successed..." << endl;

    DWORD wLen = 0;
    DWORD rLen = 0;
    char szBuffer[BUF_SIZE] = { 0 };

    //Step 4: Read and write pipeline
    while (1)
    {
        //Send data to the client
        cin.getline(szBuffer, BUF_SIZE);
        cout << "Server sends data:" << szBuffer << endl;
        if (!WriteFile(h_Mypipe, szBuffer, strlen(szBuffer) + 1, &wLen, NULL))
            cout << "Write Failed..." << endl;
        //Clear buffer
        memset(szBuffer, 0, BUF_SIZE);
    }
    //Step 5: Close the pipeline
    DisconnectNamedPipe(h_Mypipe);
    CloseHandle(h_Mypipe);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the receiving code:

```
#define BUF_SIZE 4096
HANDLE h_Mypipe = NULL;
//Step 1: Define the pipe name, dot means current host, pipe means pipe
#define MY_NAMED_PIPE   L"\\\\.\\pipe\\Named_Pipe"
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //Step 2: Determine whether there is a named pipe available
    //Function WaitNamedPipe: Wait for a certain pipeline to become available
    //Formal parameter 1: indicates the name of the named pipe
    //Formal parameter 2: NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT uses the default timeout setting when the pipe is created; NMPWAIT_WAIT_FOREVER waits forever
    if (!WaitNamedPipe(MY_NAMED_PIPE, NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT))
    {
        cout << "No Named_Pipe Accessible..." << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else
        cout << "Named_Pipe Accessible..." << endl;
    //Step 3: Open the specified named pipe
    //Function CreateFile: Create or open an object (here the object refers to the pipeline)
    h_Mypipe = CreateFile(
        MY_NAMED_PIPE, //The name of the object (pipe) created or opened
        GENERIC_READ | //Object access method: read access
        GENERIC_WRITE, //Object access method: write access
        0, //Whether the object is shared: 0 means not shared
        NULL, //Pointer to a SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES structure
        OPEN_EXISTING, //
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, //Set the attributes and flags of the object
        NULL);
    if (h_Mypipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        cout << "Open Named_Pipe Failed..." << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    DWORD wLen = 0;
    DWORD rLen = 0;
    char szBuffer[BUF_SIZE] = { 0 };

    //Step 4: Read and write pipeline
    while (1)
    {
        //Read server-side data
        if (!ReadFile(h_Mypipe, szBuffer, BUF_SIZE, &rLen, NULL))
            cout << "Read Failed..." << endl;
        else
            cout << "The client receives server-side data:" << szBuffer << endl;
        //Clear buffer
        memset(szBuffer, 0, BUF_SIZE);
    }
    //Step 5: Close the pipeline
    CloseHandle(h_Mypipe);
    return 0;
}
```

The way they work is as follows:

[image]

Comment: i love you long time, but i have a question, it's give me an error with the defined MY_NAMED_PIPE

Comment: @SerbanMarin-Eusebiu You can show the cause of the error so I can help you troubleshoot it.

Comment: problem solved, but now, when i try to run the program, always fail when creating the pipe

Comment: @SerbanMarin-Eusebiu Use `GetLastError` to view the error code, which will determine the specific cause of the error.

Comment: it's show's that the error is 123

Comment: @SerbanMarin-Eusebiu You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454578/createnamedpipe-error-invalid-name) thread, also you can show the modified part of the code.

Comment: Well, really appreciate your patience and your work, thank you very much for all the help, it worked <3

Comment: oha hayvan herif....

Answer (score 0):

Those two processes are independent form each other. Thus, you need to find a propper way to communicate between these disjunct processes.

Here are some examples on how to do that:

- Use a file as persistence (poor mans way)
- Use [Corba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Object_Request_Broker_Architecture)
- [Boost InterProcess](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/interprocess.html)

There are many more ways to do this and the choice depends on your requirements.

Comment: those methods are not allowed in what i need, this need to be done, on the easy way, i mean, FindWindow, SetConsoleTitle etc

Comment: What do you mean by saying it is not allowed? Is this some homework/exercise?

Comment: yes, it is an exercise that require this in my algorithm

Comment: The Corba and Boost methods require 3rd party libraries. Inter-process technologies that are built in to Windows include pipes, mailslots, sockets, ActiveX/COM, RPC, shared memory, clipboard, window messages, ...

Comment: that's the problem, i can't use 3rd party libraries

Comment: @SerbanMarin-Eusebiu If this is just an exercise and you are not allowed to use third party libraries, I suggest that you use a file to persist the data you like to send to the other process. One process writes a file. The  other process loops until it finds the file, reads its content and finally deletes it. This is an UNSTABLE solution, but should be the least amount of work.